# Equal height via script

Tags: javascript, jquery

It's a pain to use equal height with pure css that support at least ie9 and good browsers. 
So, I'm decided to use js instead. If there's no js enabled on the user side, having not equal heights are the least of my problems.

However, I have a very specific request on this "equal height" situation.

Using **flex**, with the help of other SO user, we can have:

http://jsfiddle.net/4an5r1b3/1/

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col left">
        <p>lorem ipsium</p>
        <p>lorem ipsium</p>
        <p>lorem ipsium</p>
        <p>lorem ipsium</p>
        <div class="bottom-yeah">
            <p>lorem ipsium</p>
            <p>lorem ipsium</p>
            <p>lorem ipsium</p>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="col right"> 
        <p>lorem ipsium</p>    
        <p>lorem ipsium</p>    
        <p>lorem ipsium</p>
        <p>lorem ipsium</p>
        <p>lorem ipsium</p>
        <p>lorem ipsium</p>
        <p>lorem ipsium</p>
        <p>lorem ipsium</p>
        <p>lorem ipsium</p>
        <p>lorem ipsium</p>
        <p>lorem ipsium</p>
        <p>lorem ipsium</p>
        <p>lorem ipsium</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**
    .container{
        display: flex;
    }

```
.col {
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    color: #fff;
}

.col.left {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: red;
}

.col.right {
    background-color: blue;
}

.bottom-yeah {
    flex-grow: 1;
    margin-top: 50px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

I'm wondering if we can achieve the same thing, 
using jquery so that, old browsers could behave as well?

Any known script that does this, so that we don't re-invent the wheel here?

Comment: If you only have textual data, why not use `table` then?

Comment: This an example. I don't have only textual data. It could be anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
var leftHeight = $('.col.left').height();
var rightHeight = $('.col.right').height();

if (leftHeight > rightHeight)
{
   $('.col.right').height(leftHeight);
} else {
   $('.col.left').height(rightHeight);
}
```

If your site is responsive, you can put this in a function and call it on $(window).resize

Comment: If you do attach it to the resize you'll probably want to throttle the function.

Comment: How would that make the yellow portion to touch the blue one? That will make columns of equal height I believe. No? I will investigate further. Thanks for your time.